# Can you use the Animus to access memories of another person you are not descended from?

Tags: video-games, assassins-creed

From what I recall, Animus works in the following way.

X has an ***ancestor***, Y. X and Y share genetic material. X can access Y's memory through the Animus simulation.

In *Assassin's Creed Valhalla*, near the endgame after the "Brother’s Keeper" mission, a certain person uses the Animus and simulates a memory of Eivor.

The original user has genes common with Eivor, being his/her descendant, but the new user does not. How is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

This was discussed at some length [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/289109-assassins-creed-valhalla/79197570) (given the similar phrasing, I don't know if this was you asking it). The conclusion seemed to fall along two lines:

1. Starting with *Assassin's Creed IV: Black Flag*, it seems that [one only needs genetic material of the ancestor to access their memories in the Animus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassin%27s_Creed_IV:_Black_Flag#Plot).
2. Due to his nature as a person in the past who was able to project themselves as a signal to the future and be reborn, Basim is inherently part of the Animus, and therefore transcends its limits.

Comment: +1 for the gamespot link (wasn’t my question). Accessing random people’s memories seems like a plausible explanation - though do  the games/Ubisoft actually confirm that?

Comment: The second point is less likely. Animus is a machine and  a software. Basim does not modify the Animus programming or hardware anywhere in the game -  his skills should have no effect on the machine.